# Is it legal to light and send off sky lanterns on the beaches of Hawaii?

Tags: legal, beaches, activities, hawaii

My family is traveling to Hawaii, specifically, Oahu next spring, and we wanted to do activities that included the entire family. We have always wanted to release [sky lanterns](https://www.groupon.com/deals/gg-sky-lanterns-24-pack-10) into the sky because it would be perfect with a Hawaii sunset and a beautiful memory to have. However, we are not sure if it's legal to do on the beaches of Hawaii? (We live in the mountains in a fire hazard zone so it's not legal where we live, but over the Pacific Ocean, wouldn't it be less of a risk?)

Does anyone know if Sky Lanterns are legal to lit and send off on the beaches of Hawaii, specifically Oahu?

We really, really want to do this:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Sea breezes often blow inland, so the floating lanterns could easily drift inland.

Comment: Hawaii is probably just as mountainous as where you live.

Answer (score 13):

Sky lanterns are banned in Hawaii. In July 2012, Hawaii Governor Neil Abercrombie signed into law HB2113, a bill which imposed a total ban on aerial luminaries, including the ignition, possession, sale or use.